# does anyone have a solution for the coin problem, when using R?

Tags: r

There are four types of common coins in   US   currency:

quarters   (25 cents)
  dimes   (10 cents)
  nickels   (5 cents),   and
  pennies   (1 cent)

There are six ways to make change for 15 cents:

A dime and a nickel
  A dime and 5 pennies
  3 nickels
  2 nickels and 5 pennies
  A nickel and 10 pennies
  15 pennies

Task:

How many ways are there to make change for a dollar using these common coins?     (1 dollar = 100 cents).

Comment: Show your effort! What did you try?

Comment: You need to provide an initial code base we can review and build upon. Otherwise it's very hard to get help.

Comment: The question looks pretty clear to me. Although initial code is missing, closing seems a bit harch for a new user. But next time, it's better to show the effords you already made (or say that you'va got no clue where to begin ;-) , we've all been there ).

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr**
There are 242 possibilities to make 1 dollar out of an unlimited supply of 1, 5, 10 and 25 cent-pieces.

**code**
here is a go at it using the `comboGeneral()`-function from the `RcppAlgos`-package.

Just set `sum_constraint` to the sum you want the coins values to add up to.

```
library(RcppAlgos)
library(data.table)

# possible coin-values
vec <- c( 1, 5, 10, 25 )
#desired sum
sum_constraint <- 15

l <- lapply( 1:sum_constraint / min(vec) , function(x) {
  #calculate possible combinations (output = matrix)
  temp <- comboGeneral( vec, 
                        m = x, 
                        repetition = TRUE, 
                        constraintFun = "sum",
                        comparisonFun = "==", 
                        limitConstraints = sum_constraint )
  #create rowwise frequency-table of the freshly created matrix,
  #and convert the table to a data.frame
  as.data.frame.matrix( table( c( row(temp)), c(temp) ) )
  })

#bind the list together to a data.table
answer <- rbindlist(l, idcol = "no_coins", use.names = TRUE, fill = TRUE )
#set missing values to 0
answer[ is.na(answer) ] <- 0
#output
answer
```

**sum_constraint = 15**

```
#    no_coins 5 10  1
# 1:        2 1  1  0
# 2:        3 3  0  0
# 3:        6 0  1  5
# 4:        7 2  0  5
# 5:       11 1  0 10
# 6:       15 0  0 15
```

**sum_constraint = 100**

```
#    no_coins 25 5 10   1
# 1:        4  4 0  0   0
# 2:        6  3 1  2   0
# 3:        7  3 3  1   0
# 4:        7  2 0  5   0
# 5:        8  3 5  0   0
# ---                     
# 238:       88  0 3  0  85
# 239:       91  0 0  1  90
# 240:       92  0 2  0  90
# 241:       96  0 1  0  95
# 242:      100  0 0  0 100
#      no_coins 25 5 10   1
```

Comment: I'm sure there is... just brute-force all possible combinations and check which combinations have sum 100.. but it will be waaaaay slower than the solution above.. (there are about 4^100 = 1.606938e+60 possibilities to check for a sum of 100 when using a (very) dumb loop).

Comment: i do not know that